# storing output to a list or dictionary

Tags: python

I'm using the following code as a portion of a larger program that does some error checking on a Digital Cinema Package and tries to check the validity of the XML file that lists the asses on the DCP. ANyway, this is all still very much in its infancy and I'm hoping to learn more python as a result of it.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import sys

class Parser(object):
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name

    def display(self, rename_this_list):
        tree = etree.parse(self.file_name)
        for node in tree.getiterator():
            for element in rename_this_list:
                if element in node.tag:
                    uuid=(node.text)
                    #uuid = [s.strip('urn:') for s in uuid]
                    print(uuid)

fname = sys.argv[1]
key_search_words = ['KeyId']
instance = Parser(fname)
instance.display(key_search_words)
```

when I try to store the output so that each line is a list it doesn't format the way that I would expect. Minus the urn: I'd like to be storing each line with uuid: and the following info as an element of a list.

```
urn:uuid:9851b0f6-4790-0d4c-a69d-ea8abdedd03d
urn:uuid:8317e8f3-1597-494d-9ed8-08a751ff8615
urn:uuid:5d9b228d-7120-344c-aefc-840cdd32bbfc
urn:uuid:1e32ccb2-ab0b-9d43-b879-1c12840c178b
urn:uuid:44d04416-676a-2e4f-8995-165de8cab78d
urn:uuid:906da0c1-b0cb-4541-b8a9-86476583cdc4
urn:uuid:0fe2d73a-ebe3-9844-b3de-4517c63c4b90
urn:uuid:862fa79a-18c7-9245-a172-486541bef0c0
urn:uuid:aa2f1a88-7a55-894d-bc19-42afca589766
urn:uuid:59d6eeff-cd56-6245-9f13-951554466626
urn:uuid:14a13b1a-76ba-764c-97d0-9900f58af53e
urn:uuid:ccdbe0ae-1c3f-224c-b450-947f43bbd640
urn:uuid:dcd37f10-b042-8e44-bef0-89bda2174842
urn:uuid:9dd7103e-7e5a-a840-a15f-f7d7fe699203
```

Comment: "It doesn't format the way that I would expect"? How does it format it, then?

Comment: how would you go about iterating over every match to KeyId or another value in the key_search_words and store each match in a list? I'd like every match to fill in another element of the list. I have been able get a whole line as I displayed to populate a list.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a list, then you can try this.

```
    def display(self, rename_this_list):
        listOfNodes = []
        tree = etree.parse(self.file_name)
        for node in tree.getiterator():
            for element in rename_this_list:
                if element in node.tag:
                   # append text of element to the list 
                   # without first four characters which are "urn:"
                   listOfNodes.append(node.text[4:])
        print str(listOfNodes)
        return listOfNodes
```

Remember that keys of a dictionary have to be unique, in a dictionary you can't have two items with keys "uuid", if you want a dictionary then you can only have one dictionary with one key "uuid" and a list of all those numbers as values.

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections
class Parser(object):
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name, self.res = collections.defaultdict(list)

    def display(self, rename_this_list):
        tree = etree.parse(self.file_name)
        for node in tree.getiterator():
            for element in rename_this_list:
                if element in node.tag:
                    uuid = node.text
                    key, value = uuid[4:].split(':')
                    self.res[key].append(value)
```

Can this satisfy your need? I don't know the details of your data so if anything wrong please tell. I think the result should be like this:

```
{'uuid':['9851b0f6-4790-0d4c-a69d-ea8abdedd03d','ccdbe0ae-1c3f-224c-b450-947f43bbd640',...]}
```

Comment: let me give this a shot. Can you elaborate on how this will look when I instantiate the object? And what about if my search terms are more expansive etc?

Comment: I don't think anything will happen except you instance will get a property `res`. @user1124541